# ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification always

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create or replace trigger after_insert_ELECTONICS1
after insert on ELECTRONICS
on each row
declare
a number;
b varchar2(50);
c blob;
d varchar2(50);
e number;
f number;
g timestamp(6);
h varchar2(20);
begin
select (post_id,title,,photo,product_type,user_user_id,product_product_id,time_date,city)
into 
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) 
from ELECTRONICS;
insert into post values (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
end;
```

What is the problem here?
I have read many answers that you have given .
but I am not able to find the problem

Comment: And what is the error you get? `on each row` should be `FOR each row`

Comment: You also don't need the variables. You can do a `insert into .. select ...` without the need for a `select .. into`

Comment: there's also a comma too much after title. Your trigger name has a typo in it. You are selecting on the table your after row insert trigger is on, causing you to run into mutating table errors, while you could just use the `:NEW` values. This question has nothing to do with apex. Er, yeah.